# Unable to draw any sort of button on Menu Screen of libgdx game(android)

Tags: android, button, libgdx

I want to display Text Buttons on main screen of my game to navigate further.But I'm unable to do so.I referred libgdx documentation but nothing seems working.I have an Image as a Game background and want to display button over it.

Here is what I want :[image] 
Below is my code.Kindly help.Thanks.

```
public void create(){

            stage = new Stage();
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

            Skin skin = new Skin();
            skin.add("logo", new Texture("ic_launcher.png"));

            Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Format.RGBA8888);
            pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            pixmap.fill();
            skin.add("white", new Texture(pixmap));

            // Store the default libgdx font under the name "default".
            skin.add("default", new BitmapFont());

            // Configure a TextButtonStyle and name it "default". Skin resources are stored by type, so this doesn't overwrite the font.
            TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
            textButtonStyle.up = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.DARK_GRAY);
            textButtonStyle.down = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.DARK_GRAY);
            textButtonStyle.checked = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.BLUE);
            textButtonStyle.over = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            textButtonStyle.font = skin.getFont("default");
            skin.add("default", textButtonStyle);

            // Create a table that fills the screen. Everything else will go inside this table.
            Table table = new Table();
            table.setFillParent(true);
            stage.addActor(table);

            // Create a button with the "default" TextButtonStyle. A 3rd parameter can be used to specify a name other than "default".
            final TextButton button = new TextButton("Click me!", skin);
            table.add(button);

            table.add(new Image(skin.newDrawable("white", Color.RED))).size(64);

} 

  public void render(float delta) {
        /*Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,1.0f,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);*/

        camera.update();
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(splsh, 0, 0,800,500);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
        Table.drawDebug(stage);
        game.batch.end();

        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            dispose();
        }
    }
```

As of now I just want either button,text button or Image button.

Comment: Show your render() method please.

Comment: @noone : Please check my updated code in question :)

Comment: Try to add the button, before you add the Table to the stage. Maybe that helps?

Comment: @Springrbua : thanks for having a look at code.But no change..

Comment: Try to move the `stage.draw()` out of the batch.begin() / batch.end(). It uses it own batch.

Comment: @noone lol this is the answer to so many "libgdx xxx is not drawn" questions and stil i did not think about that xD Jigar Pandya this should solve it...

Comment: I'd now try to use the skin at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data (uiskin), maybe there is something wrong with your skin. I have never constructed one myself programmatically like you.

Comment: @JigarPandya solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your code in `render()` looks very strange.

The first of all separate calls of your own `game.batch` and stage methods.
Then your `render()` method should look so:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,1.0f,1); // You should call this method only once outside of draw()
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(splsh, 0, 0,800,500);
    /* 
     * Render here everything that uses your camera and batch,
     * and is not a part of your stage.
     */
    game.batch.end();

    // And here is stage acts...
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
    Table.drawDebug(stage);

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        dispose();
    }
}
```

Now you should see all of your stage actors.

By the way, by default stage manage it's own camera and batch, so you don't have to do such things.

Hope this will helpful, good luck.